# Replace all instances in string with a variable as the search - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue which I cannot find documented anywhere, i see a regex method however that is using a direct string rather than string within a variable. This is my code:

```
var src = getQueryVariable("srcStr");

            if(src != false){
               $(".entry-content").html($(".entry-content")
              .html().replace(/src/g, "<span style='background-color:#f2e128;'>" 
              + src + "</span>"));

}
```

This gets a url variable (srcStr) and searches a body of text within .entry-content for the string stored in the var `src`.

The problem code is here: `replace(/src/g`

Is there a solution?

Comment: I might not understand what you're trying to say, but anytime you see a method that asks for a string, you can use a variable that's storing a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are searching for the pattern that is literally "src."  You need to use the `RegExp` class if you want to use variables in patterns:

```
pattern = new RegExp(src, 'g');
$(".entry-content")...html().replace(pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: This advice is flawed. Don't recommend building regular expressions from strings without also saying that the string *must* be regex-quoted first.

Comment: Just a note of caution: if the `src` string contains special chars (mainly `\`) you'll need to escape that char