# Using a variable within a regular expression (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to replace all instances of a string within a variable, but the string I'm looking for is also a variable. How can I add this string within a regex?

```
var myVar = HelloWorldHello;
var myString = Hello;

myVar = myVar.replace(/\\' + myString + '/g, '');
```

The above doesn't seem to be working. I need to end up with `World`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683606/replace-all-instances-in-string-with-a-variable-as-the-search-javascript

Comment: prasad's answer answered my question far clearer than either of the linked questions that I am an apparent duplicate of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use with [`new RegExp('string', 'g')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var myVar = 'HelloWorldHello';
var myString = 'Hello';

myVar = myVar.replace(new RegExp(myString, 'g'), '');
console.log(myVar)
```